# Proving limit of an analytic function $f(z)$ on $z_0$, $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} = f'(z_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis

I'm trying to prove the following

> If $f$ analytic on $z_0$ and $f(z_0) = 0$, prove that
> $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} = f'(z_0)$

So far I've been reading about poles, residue and zeros, I'm thinking to prove this, I need to argue about the zeroes of the function, is this correct?

Any insight would really help, thanks beforehand

edit: it seems like I'm taking this too far, should've tried using simple means first, that is the definition of $f'(z_0)$

Comment: What is the definition of $f'(z_0)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yeah, I should tried arguing by the definition first, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this follows directly from the definition of the derivative:

$$f'(z) = \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$$

Comment: my god, it seems like I'm taking this too far, thank you very much!